# How to display UTF-8 Chars in VB.NET Button?

Tags: html, vb.net, button, utf-8, character-encoding

I have the following code:

```
<asp:Button ID="uxSaveButton" runat="server" />

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    uxSaveButton.Text = "&#220;Test"
End Sub
```

I would see in the button the `ÜTest` but I see only `&#220;Test`

Is there any way to solve it?

I tried to add to the page this, but doesnt helps, so need other way:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Please keep in mind, `&#220;` is just an example, any similar value can came from database.

Comment: I don't know the solution but I've seen this before. ASP.NET encode almost everything that needs to be displayed on screen.

Answer (score 2):

You are putting the HTML entity for the character in the text, so it will be converted to the HTML code for showing that entity as text. It will end up as `&amp;#220;` in the rendered code.

Put the character itself in the text. Example:

```
uxSaveButton.Text = Chr(220) + "Test"
```

#### Edit:

For any actual text that you get from the database this would not be a problem. The characters would not be HTML entities. If you have HTML code stored in the database (which is generally not the best approach) then you can decode it to get it back as text:

```
uxSaveButton.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(str)
```

Comment: Nice solution could be, But anything can came from the database, what can be the Text of the button.

Comment: @Krekkon: If you get text from the database, then it shouldn't be a problem. If you have HTML code stored in the database (which is generally not the best approach), then you can use `Server.HtmlDecode` to decode it back into text.

Answer (score 1):

You could `HtmlDecode` the value before assigning it to the `Button.Text` property:

```vb
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    MyButton.Text = Server.HtmlDecode("&#220;Test")
End Sub
```

This results in a button like this:

[image: Button screen shot]